# Any Dart List Method that works this way?

Tags: list, dart, methods

```
class Word{
String word;
Word({required this.word});
}
```

```
List<Word> firstList = ["Add","All","Human","Moon","Free"];
List<Word> secondList= ["Add","Human","Free"];
```

If the element in the first list exists in the second list, I want it to return true, otherwise false.

Output that should be:

```
true
false
true
false
true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd make sure that `Word` can be compared easily:

```
class Word {
  String word;
  Word({required this.word});

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if (identical(this, other)) return true;

    return other is Word && other.word == word;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => word.hashCode;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
print(firstList.map((w) => secondList.contains(w)));
```

Check this [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=204f2ca42f5b8789314a1a1c417ae06f) for it